# Como criar um template de arquivo texto?

Tags: c#

Como eu faço para utilizar um template de arquivo de extensão `txt`, de tal forma que meu programa consiga ler esse template, substituir pontos específicos dele e gerar uma saída, por exemplo, em outro arquivo `txt`. Por exemplo:

Arquivo_template.txt

```
Propriedade1: {aqui será substituído pela variável_1}
Propriedade2: {aqui será substituído pela variável_2}
...
```

É possível utilizar esse esquema de template? Ou eu tenho que gerar o arquivo manualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nativamente você só tem `String.Replace` e `RegEx.Replace`, mesmo.

Eu sugiro usar um pacote pronto como [StringTokenFormatter](https://github.com/andywilsonuk/StringTokenFormatter) ou [NamingFormatter](https://github.com/kekyo/CenterCLR.NamingFormatter), ou mesmo um *engine* de *templates*, como por exemplo o [RazorEngine](http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é você estabelecer uma convenção para os textos que devem ser substituídos, com algum símbolo ou tipo de pontuação para as variáveis do seu arquivo. Por exemplo, `:{}`

A seguinte função pode ser útil para executar a função:

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public static string TrocarTokens(string template, Dictionary<string, string> dicionarioVariaveis)
    {
        var rex = new Regex(@"\:{([^}]+)}");
        return(rex.Replace(template, delegate(Match m)
        {
            string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
            string rep = dicionarioVariaveis.ContainsKey(key)? dicionarioVariaveis[key] : m.Value;
            return(rep);
        }));
    }
```

Template adaptado:

```
Propriedade1: :{variavel_1}
Propriedade2: :{variavel_2}
...
```

Uso:

```
var dicionarioValores = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dicionarioValores["variavel_1"] = "Valor 1";
dicionarioValores["variavel_2"] = "Valor 2";
var saida = TrocarTokens(stringDoArquivo, dicionarioValores);
```

[Tirei a ideia daqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/akirsman/2011/09/13/c-token-replacement-using-regex/).

Comment: Legal, mas dessa forma eu sempre teria que ler todas as linhas do arquivo de template para poder substituir numa string gigantesca, né? Não teria algo parecido só que nativo do c#?

Comment: Nativo não conheço, mas acho que não.